# Changing the color of the range slider in materializecss

Tags: css, materialize

I'm using the range slider from here: http://materializecss.com/forms.html

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.8/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.8/js/materialize.js"></script>

<form action="#">
    <p class="range-field">
      <input type="range" id="test5" min="0" max="100" />
    </p>
  </form>
```

And I managed to change the color of the "thumb" that pops up when you click on the slider by using this:

```
input[type=range]+.thumb{
    background-color: #400090;
}
```

And normally I can just inspect the element on chrome and get what class I have to change to change its color. For some reasons I can't figure out how to inspect the "dot" in the slider to find what class I have to add to change its color.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is what I did to change the dot on the slider and the thumb bubble colors.

Screenshot and snippet attached

[image]

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.8/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.8/js/materialize.js"></script>

<style>

  input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    background-color: red;
  }
  input[type=range]::-moz-range-thumb {
    background-color: red;
  }
  input[type=range]::-ms-thumb {
    background-color: red;
  }

  /***** These are to edit the thumb and the text inside the thumb *****/
  input[type=range] + .thumb {
    background-color: #dedede;
  }
  input[type=range] + .thumb.active .value {
    color: red;
  }
</style>
<form action="#">
  <p class="range-field">
    <input type="range" id="test5" min="0" max="100" />
  </p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    .noUi-connect {
    background: black;
}
.noUi-horizontal .noUi-handle, .noUi-vertical .noUi-handle {
    background: black;
}
.noUi-target.noUi-horizontal .noUi-tooltip {
    background-color: black;
}
```

[check out this pen by alexventuraio](https://codepen.io/alexventuraio/pen/MqYboo)

you can also do

```
document.querySelector('.noUi-tooltip').style.background = 'black';
document.querySelector('.noUi-handle').style.background = 'black';
```

Use querySelector all to change all.    CSS [" .noUi-handle{...} and .noUi... "] is not overriding.

I'm new to stack

Comment: You should probably delete this as it doesn't answer the original question.

Comment: He wants to change the color of the range slider in MaterializeCSS overriding the class ' .noUi-tooltip ' will change the Range slider tooltip and overriding other noUi... classes change color generally. Today I used these codes to change my Range slider color!!!  how it cannot be useful? I'm not a native English speaker if there are any mistakes in English excuse me :)

Comment: He found it difficult in navigating to the required doms style by this way he can achieve the style....

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to figure this out is actually by looking through the source code. Hosted here (https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/blob/master/forms.html) in line 833 and here (https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/blob/master/sass/components/forms/_range.scss) on Github.

Between this and my Chrome DevTools, I have managed to change the background on the range input to #4286f4(substitute for you color) with this CSS declaration:

```
.noUI-connect {
  background: #4286f4 ;
}
```

You may need to use the !important flag on the property. This changes the color of the slider between the two .thumb elements.

To change the color of the little "thumbs" on the slider:

```
.range-label{
  background-color: desired-color;
}
```

If you would like to change the grey-color of the background(area outside selection), use this:

```
.noUI-background {
  background: desired-color;
}
```

Additional Caveat: This solution was only tested on the noUiSlider implementation: http://materializecss.com/forms.html (scroll to Range section). I have not tested this on a plain HTML range element, and sadly need to get back to work.

EDIT:
Having tried to explore solutions on the plain html range input, it appears that there is  tag with the class "value" on the slider, as a child of .thumb. Unfortunately, styling this has not led anywhere, leading me to believe that this is either a :before/:after css property, or that your answer lies between lines 73-83 of the 2nd link in the first paragraph.

Comment: Thanks for the input! I suppose the only way would be to dig through the css and figure out where they set the dot color. I'm not trying to change the thumb nor the grey slider, just the "button"